# Sending base64_image via jquery to php form and my email...image not shown

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a problem of using the jquery to send the base64_image to my form and echo it on that page for customers to preview. as that form is for customers to fill in their information and double check the image, once they have confirmed, the data they fill in will send to my email address. However, the image cannot shown in the preview section and in email as well.

For the base64_image, is customers using the jquery to create their design picture. Please find below code for your ref.

index.php

```
 $('#send-button').click(function(){
                    fpd.createImage(true, true);
                    return false;
                });

                //the handler when the image is created
                $('#fpd').bind('imageCreate', function(evt, canvas, base64Image) {
                    //send 64-bit encoded image url to php
                    $.post("php/form.php", { base64_image: base64Image }, function(data) {
                        //successful
                        if(data) {
                            //open product image a new window
                            console.log('Mail successfully sent!');
                        }
                        //failed
                        else {
                            console.log('Mail could not be sent');
                        }
                    } );
                });     





<a href="php/form.html" id="send-button" class="btn btn-info">send</a>
```

form.php

```
<form name= "myForm" form action="send.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

 <td align="right" valign="middle" class="text">Picture Preview:<img src="<?=$base64_str;?>"></img></td>

</form>
```

send.php

```
$base64_str = substr($_POST['base64_image'], strpos($_POST['base64_image'], ",")+1);

$to =   'xxx@gmail.com';//set here your receiving mail address
$subject =  'test'; //set here the mail subject
$bound_text =   md5(date('r', time()));
$bound =    "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
$bound_last =   "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";

$headers =  "From: xxx@yahoo.com.hk\r\n";//set here the sending mail address
$headers .=     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

$message .=     "If you can see this MIME than your client doesn't accept MIME types!\r\n"
    .$bound;

$message .=     "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
    ."Your message goes here\r\n" //set here the mail text
    .$bound;

$message .=     "Content-Type: image/png; name=\"mail_product.png\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
    ."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"mail_product.png\"\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    .chunk_split($base64_str)
    .$bound_last;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
     echo json_encode(1);
} else {
     echo json_encode(0);
}  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats the problem? Sending the email or show the preview, or both?

Do the jQuery script sent the data to the php file correctly? Have you debug this?

What is the returning value in (data)? Do you get 0, 1 or something else?

Do you have set up your own smtp mail server or using gmail`s smtp server?

Comment: Hi q0re, the image cannot view in the form.php and also in my email account....no attachement

Comment: You get the email? But there is no attachment?

Comment: have you test if `$base64_str` is null?

Comment: I have take out the form.php and post it to send.php directly, the image shown///

 $.post("php/send.php", { base64_image: base64Image }, function(data) {
                        //successful

Comment: Hmm okay..
change  
`Content-disposition`  
to  
`Content-Disposition`  
Maybe this will fix the problem..
  
I have written a mail function (with attachment) a view days ago.. and everything works fine.. I compare the solutions and i can't find any error ..

Comment: ohhh but how about the preview section？as the image cannot shown in the form.php

Comment: Do you now get the email with attachment?
The form of src must be `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />`. Do you have the correct form with `data:image/png;base64,`? Is $base64_str in form.php set or empty?

Comment: image64 in form.php is empty...as need to post from index.php

Comment: When you are sending the base64 image to form.php you need to access the variable with $_POST['base64_image']. So change it to `<img src="<?php echo 'data:image/png;base64,' . $_POST['base64_image']; ?>"`

Comment: Do you sent the post of jQuery to "php/form.php" or send.php?

Comment: Why did you seperate the show and sent in 2 files? You can put all in one file or post the image from index.php to send.php and after successfull sent post the image to form.php (better show.php).